# get date and time format from mac OS x system settings

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, date, format

Is there any way to get the time and date format from the 'Language & Text' setting on Mac OS x in Java code? If not in Java, can that be done without using cocoa framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no support for this in the standard Java API. The closest match for your need is probably the [`DateFormat.getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getInstance%28%29) which gives you the default date format for the default locale on your system.

For the specific format in the *Language & Text* settings you would have to rely on some native library for solving this.

I can however definitely see the usefulness of such library, so if you decide to go through with it I encourage you to make it open source and let people add support for more operating systems.